# Facebook monetization placement violation solution?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-monetization-manager

I have some ad placements (like thin banner/ rectangle ad) in android app, one of them is like shown below. This ad is shown at the end of scrollable text content. This ad is blocked 3rd time in this month. They email me with [policy link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/policy). I have read this policy thoroughly but I am unable to find out the solution.

Please note that this ad was running from 3 months. But when app started having good user installs, then they blocked it.

**What I thought while developing:**

1. It will not be disturbing user.
2. I am integrating ad with a good manner.
3. User always knows that it is ad after a long text description.

**What actually happens:**

1. Ad placement has been blocked 3 times.
2. They say it violates policy.

I asked facebook team to help me out to find the issue in placement, like these lines

> It is hard to identify violations without any suggestions. I am not
>   able to find out issue. Please help to identify issue.

Facebook team says -

> We will not be able to advise you on how to improve your placements or
>   provide any further information on this matter.

Do you have any idea why this placement is against the policies?

[image: ad placement]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because terms of use of a third party service are off topic here.

Comment: @GabeSechan please suggest some platform to get help regarding this problem.